# Using the lips package

Tags: errors

How do I use the `lips` package?

Having the following line in my preamble:

```
\usepackage{lips}
```

produces the following error:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/frankenstein/lips.sty:309: Undefined control sequence.
l.309 \newlet\lips
                  \Lips
```

Why so?

Comment: That's not the error I get. I get `\newlet` is the undefined control sequence, not `\lips`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are supposed to use it with the other “frankenstein package” `moredefs` included first. `moredefs` defines

```
\newcommand*\newlet [2] {% args: \csname-a \csname-b
  \@ifdefinable #1 {%
    \let #1#2%
  }%
}
```

`\@ifdefinable` is defined in the LaTeX source (`texdoc source2e`) and is the same check that is used in `\newcommand` to check that nothing is overwritten.

Comment: Taking off from your answer, I searched for `moredefs` in `texdoc lips`. It's in Section 5, and not in some "Getting Started" section `:(`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug in the package. It also looks like `docstrip` was not run on the package and a `lips.dtx` file was just renamed to `lips.sty`.

It seems to work for me if I use.

```
\let\newlet\let
\usepackage{lips}
```